# Unset all ENV variables matching _PROXY

Tags: awk, grep, environment-variables, xargs

I'm trying to unset all environment variables that match `_PROXY`:

```
env | grep -i _proxy | column -t -s '=' | awk '{ print $1 }' | grep -iv 'no_proxy' | xargs -0 -I variable unset variable
```

but it's failing with `xargs: unset: No such file or directory`.

If I try changing `unset` to `echo`, however, everything seems to work as expected: I get a list of variables that are set.

```
env | grep -i _proxy | column -t -s '=' | awk '{ print $1 }' | grep -iv 'no_proxy' | xargs -0 -I variable echo variable
http_proxy
ftp_proxy
FTP_PROXY
https_proxy
HTTPS_PROXY
HTTP_PROXY
```

What seems to be going wrong?  (If you have an alternate strategy for accomplishing the goal, I'm interested, but I'd *most of all* like to know why this is failing.)

Also, I'm using OS X, in case that's relevant.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's because `unset` is a [shell builtin](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/unset) and not an external command. This means that `xargs` can't use it since that only runs commands that are in your `$PATH`. You'd get the same problem if you tried with `cd`:

```
$ ls -l
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 terdon terdon 4096 Jun 16 02:02 foo
$ echo foo | xargs cd
xargs: cd: No such file or directory
```

One way around this is to use a shell loop which, since it is part of the shell, will be able to run shell builtins. I also simplified your command a bit, there's no need for `column`, you can set the field separator for `awk` and there's no need for a second `grep`, just tell `awk` to print lines that don't match `no_proxy`:

```
while read var; do unset $var; done < <(env | grep -i proxy | 
    awk -F= '!/no_proxy/{print $1}')
```

Answer (score 8):

```
unset `env | grep _PROXY | egrep -o '^[^=]+'`
```

Comment: Much simpler to remember than the `while read var` method.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the answer that terdon wrote, but with `sed`:

```
while read var; do unset $var; done < <(env | grep -i _proxy | sed 's/=.*//g')
```